# ExtJS/Javascript which runs locally (localhost) but not remotely

Tags: javascript, java, extjs, extjs4

I have following Javascript/ExtJS code

---

```
Ext.define('KLIFT.view.vPavimento', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',

title: 'Pavimentos',
closeAction: 'destroy',
autoShow: true,
height: 400,
width: 400,
layout: 'fit',
modal: true,

idObra: null,

afterRender: function() {
    var me = this;

    me.gridPavimento = me.down('grid[name=gridPavimento]');
    me.botaoSalvar = me.down('button[name=botaoSalvar]');
    me.botaoCancelar = me.down('button[name=botaoCancelar]');

    if(me.idObra != null){
        me.carregaGrid();
    }

    me.callParent(arguments);
},

carregaGrid: function(){
    var me = this;

    me.setLoading(true);
    alert('cai aqui');
    me.gridPavimento.store.load({
        params: {
            idObra: me.idObra

        },
        callback: function(){
            me.setLoading(false);
        }
    });
},

desabilitarControles: function(o){
    var me = this;

    var opcao = false;

    if(o == true){
        opcao = true;
    }

    me.botaoSalvar.setDisabled(opcao);
    me.botaoCancelar.setDisabled(opcao);
},

salvarAlteracoes: function(){
    var me = this;

    me.gridPavimento.store.sync();
},

cancelarAlteracoes: function(){
    var me = this;

    me.gridPavimento.store.rejectChanges();
    me.gridPavimento.store.sort();
},

adicionarVarios: function(){
    var me = this;

    Ext.MessageBox.show({
        title: 'Criar varios pavimentos',
        msg: 
            '<table><tr><td>Quantidade de pavimentos:</td><td><input id="qtde" type="text" /></td></tr><tr><td>Medida pe direito:</td><td><input id="pdPadrao" pattern="[0-9.]+" type="number"   /></td></tr></table>',
        buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OKCANCEL,
        fn: function(btn) {
            if(btn == 'ok') {

                me.setLoading(true);

                //var qtde = Ext.get('qtde').getValue();
                //var pdPadrao = Ext.get('pdPadrao').getValue();

                quant = document.getElementById('qtde').value;
                pd = document.getElementById('pdPadrao').value;


                //pdPadrao = parseFloat(pdPadrao.replace(',', '.'));

                if(quant != "" && pd != ""){
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        async: false, 
                        url: '../pavimento/criarVarios',
                        method: 'GET',
                        params: {
                            idObra: me.idObra,
                            qtde: quant,
                            pdPadrao: pd
                        },
                        success: function(){
                            me.carregaGrid();
                        },
                        callback: function(){
                            me.setLoading(false);
                        }
                    });
                } else{
                    me.adicionarVarios();
                }
            }
        }
    });
},

initComponent: function(){
    var me = this;

    Ext.apply(me, {
        tbar: [{
            icon: '../img/add.png',
            text: 'Adicionar',
            handler: function(){
                me.gridPavimento.adicionaPavimento();
            }
        },{
            icon: '../img/delete.png',
            text: 'Remover',
            handler: function(){
                me.gridPavimento.removePavimento();
            }
        },{
            icon: '../img/add.png',
            text: 'Adicionar Varios',
            handler: function(){
                me.adicionarVarios();
            }
        }],
        bbar: [{
         icon: '../img/up.png',
            text: 'Sobe',
            handler: function(){
                me.gridPavimento.sobePavimento();
            }
        },{
            icon: '../img/down.png',
            text: 'Desce',
            handler: function(){
                me.gridPavimento.descePavimento();
            }
        },{
            icon: '../img/accept.png',
            name: 'botaoSalvar',
            text: 'Salvar Alteracoes',
            handler: function(){
                me.salvarAlteracoes();
            }
        },{
            icon: '../img/cross.gif',
            name: 'botaoCancelar',
            text: 'Cancelar Alteracoes',
            handler: function(){
                me.cancelarAlteracoes();
            }
        }],
        items: Ext.create('KLIFT.grid.gPavimento')
    });

    me.callParent(arguments);
}
```

});

---

This call below

Ext.Ajax.request({
                            async: false, 
                            url: '../pavimento/criarVarios',
                            method: 'GET',
                            params: {
                                idObra: me.idObra,
                                qtde: quant,
                                pdPadrao: encodeURIComponent(pd)
                            },

will call a java code in server side as below:

```
@Get
public void criarVarios(Long idObra, int qtde, Double pdPadrao) throws Exception{

    try{
        session.beginTransaction();

        dao.excluirPorObra(idObra);

        for (int i = 1; i <= qtde; i++) {
            Pavimento p = new Pavimento();
            p.setIdObra(idObra);
            p.setPosicao(i);
            p.setMarcacaoVisual(String.valueOf(i));
            p.setMedidaPeDireito(pdPadrao);

            if(i == 1){
                p.setTerreo(true);
            }

            dao.create(p);
        }

        session.getTransaction().commit();

        String success = "true";
        result.use(Results.json()).from(success, "success").serialize();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if(session.getTransaction().isActive())
            session.getTransaction().rollback();

        throw e;
    }
}
```

when running locally with Chrome, I type decimal values into this HTML input text:

And corresponding java method accepts it as a double (like 2.5 or 3.23 or 1.457)

When I deploy such war into a remote server and access web page from Chrome browser, decimal pattern does not work for input type and value typed as 3.4 comes as 34.0 to java server-side call.

I'm using Vraptor framework in server side. Wildfly 10.2 as server. Ext-js version 4 for front end. Please help, I don't know what to do, I don't know Ext.js and had to assume a legacy project.

Comment: Could you check the request in the "Network Tab" of Chrome Dev Tools? What is the number format like of the numbers that ExtJS sends to your server in both cases?

Comment: Hi @scebotari66... It shows something like '2.3', '3.45'... theoretically data is going to Java server-side correctly. I'm stuck on that, have no idea.